# How can I do file i/o without fstream for competitions like google code jam?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

Let me preface this question by saying I am not a very experienced programmer.

For competitions like google code jam, I write code like this:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fin("file.in");
    ofstream oin("file.out");
    //Etc. I'll now write out my solution.
    //...
}
```

However, I noticed that many other code sources by other participants don't use fstream at all and use iostream instead. Then they'll use cout and cin as if they were reading and writing from the console.

How are they doing this? Can I do the same thing if I am using g++ and ubuntu?

**EDIT:** Since it was requested that I post an example of what I mean, here is code from participant ryuuga who solved large [Bot Trust, Problem A](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=975485#) from the recent '11 qualification round.

He uses cin and cout but I don't know how he is doing file i/o.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>
#include <map>
#include <set>
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
#include <vector>
typedef vector<int> vi;
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#define For(i,a,b) for(int i=(a);i<(b);++i)

#define ForI(i,a,b) for(int i=(a);i<=(b);++i)
#define ForAll(it,set) for(typeof(set.begin()) it = set.begin(); it!=set.end(); ++it)

typedef stack<int> si;
typedef queue<int> qi;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    ForI(tt,1,t){
        int n;cin>>n;
        int pos[2]={1,1}, time[2] = {0,0};
        int curTime = 0;
        For(i,0,n){
            char type; int button;
            cin>>type>>button;
            type = (type=='B'?1:0);
            int nextTime = 1+max(curTime, time[type] + abs(button - pos[type]));
            pos[type] = button;
            time[type] = nextTime;
            curTime = nextTime;
        }
        cout<<"Case #"<<tt<<": "<<curTime<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Study the source of a few of the other coders that use this technique and all should be become clear.  You can do this in any C++ implementation, so G++ / Ubuntu is fine.

Comment: How are they doing it? You tell us. You're the one who noticed it in "many other code sources," after all. Once you show the code, you can get explanations of how it works and why someone might choose that technique instead of what you've used.

Comment: The console is only a substitute for a file if you have a user that's *very* patient.  Or uses I/O redirection.  Avoid the lowest common denominator here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine when you are using the shell in ubuntu. Almost everything is read by the console, cin and written to the console, cout. For instance

```
cat "file.txt" | grep "Hello"
```

cat would get the "file.txt" from the arguments given to main, i.e.

```
main(int argc, char ** argv){
    // for the both cat and grep examples argc is 2
    // argv[1] contains "file.txt" for cat. 
    // open an ifstream and ouput it to cout. There's cat for you.
}
```

To find out what `argv[0]` contains, try it out!
`grep` would read the same argument then read everything from cin, copy the input that matches `argv[1]` to cout

EDIT: He is running his program with

```
cat "downloaded-input-file.txt" | theprogram > output.txt
```

Then submits the program. Or he might be using the `< downloaded-input-file` syntax.   I'm keeping the initial explanation as it might be useful for the understanding of the process.

Comment: Ah thank you, this makes things very clear to me! It also helps me to know what to google for more info.