# Input/Output through terminal with Codejam questions

Tags: c, file, io, file-handling

Before i start my question, i would like to declare a few things: -
This is not a copy of a question already on this site.
There happens to be a question on similar lines however, i still do not understand 'exactly' how input output has been done. As in, the answerer says that the code has

```
int main(int argc, int argv**)
{
}
```

However, in the solutions posted on the site, not even that is used. an example is this for the problem https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/1460488/dashboard#s=p0&a=0. (Speaking in tongues. I do use ubuntu terminal and tried doing as directed by [How can I do file i/o without fstream for competitions like google code jam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038137/how-can-i-do-file-i-o-without-fstream-for-competitions-like-google-code-jam). Turned out nothing was written onto my output file. Can i be better directed, how to achieve so. This is NOT a homework as i have done this already. I only need to know how to do the input output in a linux terminal.

Im also giving my code: -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEBUG 1
#define printd if (DEBUG) printf

char cipher[26] =     {'y', 'h', 'e', 's', 'o', 'c', 'v', 'x', 'd', 'u', 'i', 'g', 'l', 'b', 'k', 'r', 'z', 't', 'n', 'w', 'j', 'p', 'f', 'm', 'a', 'q'};  

int main()
{
  int count, j;
  scanf("%d\n", &count);
  for (j=0;j<count;j++)
  {
    printf("Case #%d: ",j+1);
    translate();
    printf("\n");
  }
}
void translate()
{
  char c;
  scanf("%c", &c);
  while (c != '\n')
  {
    if (c == ' ')
      printf(" ");
    else
    {
      int index = c - 'a';
      if (index >=0 && index <= 26)
      {
        printf("%c", cipher[index]);
      }
    }
    scanf("%c", &c);
  }
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: I would recommend `fgetc()` over `scanf()` any day of the week if performance is your end-goal.

Comment: So, what exactly is not working? What does your code do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: It is essentially a translator. There is a specific mapping it follows, takes the input from a file and according to the mapping writes the output to a file. That is what it does and what i expect it to do, only through the linux terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your file compiled as foo you can do the following:

```
./foo < input > output
```

This will read input and write everything you write with printf to output.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! That worked like a charm. I can now take a breath of relief, i was so tensed up about the input/output thing, even more since the event is approaching. Thanks a ton.